# Prove that the two definitions of nowhere dense sets are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I  have  these  two  definitions  of  *nowhere*  *dense*  sets

$X$ is  a  metric/topological   space. Then

$a.$) $A\subset X$  is  nowhere  dense  in  $X$   if  given  any  non  empty  open  set  $U$  there  is  a   non  empty open  subset  $V\subset U$  such  that  $A\cap V= \varnothing$

$b.$) $A\subset X$   is  nowhere  dense  iff  the  interior  of  closure  of  $A$  is  empty  i.e.  ${(\bar A)^{\circ}}= \varnothing$

Now  I  get  $a  \Rightarrow  b$  as  follows  :

When  $a$  is  given, if  $b$  is  not  true  then  there  is  $x\in X$ s.t $x\in {(\bar A)^{\circ}}$  then  there exist $r\gt 0$  s.t $B(x,r)\subset {(\bar A)^{\circ}}$

or, $B(x,r)\subset {\bar A}$

If we  take  $U=B(x,r)$ here  then  there  is  no   non  empty  open  subset  $V$   of  $U$
s.t $A\cap V = \varnothing$. This  contradicts  $a$  so $b$  must  be  true.

I  cannot  figure  out  $b\Rightarrow a$ 
Need  some  help  there.

Thanks.

Comment: For $b) \implies a)$, you have a set $A$ whose closure has empty interior. You pick a nonempty open set $U$. What is the largest open subset of $U$ that doesn't intersect $A$?

Comment: @DanielFischer :   I  think  it  is  ${{\bar A}^{c}} \cap U $  $?$

Comment: Indeed. Now, why is that nonempty?

Comment: ...I don't understand how the first definition could be correct, as it applies to $A=X$, by taking $V=U$.

Comment: @Ian Well spotted. It should of course read $A\cap V = \varnothing$. My eyes auto-corrected that.

Comment: @DanielFischer  :  If  that  is  empty ,  then  ${\bar A}\subset U$  $?$

Comment: If $E \setminus F = \varnothing$, what inclusion do we have?

Comment: @Ian : Thanks  for  pointing  out ,  that  was   typo.

Comment: @DanielFischer :  Oops , that  is  $U\subset {\bar A}$ .

Comment: Right. And why can that not be?

Comment: @DanielFischer  :  Because $U$  is  open  and  $\bar A$   has    empty  interior . Hence  $U\backslash  {\bar A}$  is  non  empty .  So  we  have  found  our  $V$ .  Right  $?$

Comment: You can now post an answer to the question, it seems.

Answer (score 10):

Suppose a subset $\;A \;$is nowhere dense according to Defn(1). Then $\;\overline{ A}\;$has empty interior. Suppose $\;U\;$is any non-empty open set. Then $\;U\;$cannot be entirely contained in $\;\overline{A}\;.\;$ Therefore $\; U\cap (X-\overline{A})\;$is a non-empty open subset of $\;U\;$disjoint from $\;\overline{A}\;$and hence disjoint from $\;A\;$also. Thus Defn(2) holds true.

Conversely, assume that a subset$\; A \;$is nowhere dense as per Defn(2),then given any non-empty open set $\;V\;,\;$there exists a non-empty open subset $\;W \subseteq V\;$disjoint from $\;A\;.\;\;$As $\;W\;$is open, it is disjoint from $\overline{A}$ also. Thus no non-empty open set can be entirely contained in $\overline{A}.\;\;$ie $\;\overline{ A}\;$has empty interior.  Hence Defn(1) holds true.
 Thus both definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$b)\implies a)$:

Since $A$ is nowhere dense, $(\overline{A})^c$ is dense and open. This means that for any open set $U,\:U\cap (\overline{A})^c\neq\varnothing$. Let $x\in U\cap (\overline{A})^c$. Then $x$ has an open neighborhood $V$ that $V\subset U\cap (\overline{A})^c\subset (\overline{A})^c$, i.e. $V\cap \overline{A}=\varnothing$. Thus
$$
V\cap {A}\subset V\cap \overline{A}=\varnothing
$$

Comment: The claim that there is an $x \in V$ and an $r>0$ such that $\emptyset \neq B(x,r) \subset int(A \cap V)$ is wrong. Take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $U = (0,1)$. The intersection $A \cap V$ is nonempty for any open $V \subset U$, but it does not contain any open ball - its interior is actually empty.

Comment: No, $\Bbb{Q}$ is not nowhere dense, but dense because $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}=(\overline{\Bbb{Q}})^o=\Bbb{R}$, while nowhere dense set is $(\overline{A})^o=\varnothing$.

Comment: Yes, every kid knows that. I did NOT write $\mathbb{Q}$ is nowhere dense (this would mean that its closure has empty interior, which obviously is not the case). But $\mathbb{Q}$ itself indeed DOES have empty interior - again: you're wrong and the claim I pointed out is wrong. To repeat: there is NO open ball $B(x,r)$ that would be included in the interior of $A \cap V$ for $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and open $V \subset U := (0,1)$, when $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You assume $A=\Bbb{Q}$. Also the closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ does not have empty interior. My proof is from a standard text of topology, and so is correct of course.

Comment: Direct us to this standard text, please. Please also read what I write... Nobody denied that the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: Now, for your incorrect proof: you assume not (a), i.e. $A \subset X$ is s.t. there is a non-empty open set $U \subset X$ and a non-empty open subset $V \subset U$ s.t. $A \cap V \neq \emptyset$. Now you claim that *IT FOLLOWS* there is $x \in V$ and $r>0$ s.t. $B(x,r) \subset int(A \cap V)$. This claim is false.

Comment: "It is a standard theorem in topology" - yes, but I am not referring to the theorem, but to your proof. Show me this textbook that contains your proof.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. To be nowhere dense, intuitively it means that it contains no balls (regardless how small). So if $A\cap V\neq\varnothing$, since $V$ is open and $(A\cap V)^o$ is open too, it must contain a ball.

Comment: NO! You say: "since $V$ is open and $int(A \cap V)$ is open too [this is true so far], it must contain a ball." - this would be the case ONLY if $int(A \cap V)$ were non-empty, but it does not follow that it has to be non-empty!

Comment: Of course the result is true - it is an extremely elementary exercise, which you did wrong. Do not refer me to text-books, please. Your proof is not solid, it is incorrect. I gave you a clear counterexample to a flawed reasoning you presented (while trying to prove a very easy result).

Comment: Your example is not valid because it is not nowhere dense. It is a bit confusing though. So I modified the proof.